# Does Python have the C++ equavalent of (var = value, var)

Tags: python, c++, expression

In C++ (and maybe C), you are able to do the following:

```cpp
uint8_t one = 0;

if ((one = randomUint8t(), one) == 255){
 printf("One has the max uint8_t value");
}
```

So you assign the value of the random uint8 function to `one`, and you return `one` to be used in the expression evaluation.

This particularly useful if you are trying to debug a while loop or if you want to assign a value to a variable unconditionally, but enter the if statement (or not) based on the new value of that same variable.

Comment: You mean the "comma operator".

Comment: For the case you've shown, `if ((one = randomUint8t()) == 255){` has the same outcome. No need for the comma operator, there.

Comment: it's not `var = value, var` but `(var = value), var` because the `=` operator has lower precedence than `,` and `var = value, var` will be parsed as `var = (value, var)`. Anyway that's expression is very silly because you just need `if (one = randomUint8t()) == 255)` as the assignment operator already returns the value

Comment: @phuclv `,` has lower precedence than `=` in both C and C++. In fact, the comma has the lowest precedence of all operators.

Comment: i do not see the benefit of yours compared to `one = randomUnit();` outside of the `if`. Anyhow `one` is declared in the outer scope

Comment: you can do the same in almost any language, but in almost no language the code will look identical or use same expressions.

Comment: @phuclv ... so `var = value, var;` will be parsed as `var = value; var;`

Comment: I wouldn't conside this more useful than `one = randomUint8t(); if (one == 255){...`, just more obfuscated and prone to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible since Python 3.8 with [assignment expressions aka the "walrus" operator `:=`](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/). Example:

```py
import random

if (one := random.randint(0, 255)) == 255:
    print("one == 255")
```

Comment: I thought that the walrus operator was for conditional assignments only

Comment: @tim687 well, you thought wrong then ! ;)